# AngularJS - Ng-route - Change ng-view when input:focus

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I would like to change my view with ng-view. The point is that instead of firing an `ng-click` event, I would need to do it when somebody starts typing in an `input:text` field (so I could achieve the same effect as when start typing in the search box in this [page](https://qatar.jadopado.com)).

PS: I tried adding `ng-click` to the input element, but that doesn't trigger the event. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tDpjJyTJw4klfHGLBXZJ?p=preview) with the correct answer provided by dfsq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to use ngChange directive with [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) (for debounce):

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-change="searchProduct()"
       ng-model="query" 
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 } }">
```

Then implementation of `changeView` is up to you, but I assume you would need to do something with `$location.path` to the change view:

```javascript
$scope.searchProduct = function() {
  // ...
  $location.search({query: $scope.query});
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I just don't understand exactly how to adapt the last line to my code. Here is the plunkr with what I have developed so far [http://plnkr.co/edit/3QwWaaCSt8PmTfbpIYi9?p=preview]

Comment: Just inject $location into controller: http://plnkr.co/edit/tDpjJyTJw4klfHGLBXZJ?p=preview

Comment: Works perfect. I mark it as correct and add the plunkr to the question.  Thanks a lot!