# AngularJS Ng-route - Switching to a particular page view when typing an input:text from another url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Sorry for the long title. This question is based in the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511072/angularjs-ng-route-change-ng-view-when-inputfocus)

I have a page with two views

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
.when('/content1', {
  templateUrl: 'content1.html',
  controller: 'myCtrl'
})

.when('/content2', {
templateUrl: 'content2.html',
controller: 'myCtrl'
})

.otherwise({
redirectTo: '/content1'
});

}]);
```

When typing into an input:text it switches to the second view using a ng-change directive that triggers the function `searchProduct()` and starts searching with an `ng-model` directive right away.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
<input type="text" 
       ng-change="searchProduct()" 
       ng-model="searchFilter" 
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 } }">
<ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Being the `searchProduct()` function

```
$scope.searchProduct = function() {
    $location.path('content2');
    $location.search({
      searchFilter: $scope.searchFilter
    });
};
```

All this is working properly. But the problem is that I would like to implement the same feature in another page with a different url (this is for SEO purposes), so that when searching in that page it would redirect to content2.html, and it would also preserve what has been typed in the search box.

I've tried to do it by setting an absolute path, but it doesn't seem to work. You can see [a working plunker with the code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M9gvAvVNBNnvFe86LprY?p=preview). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't quite understand the question but have you tried putting the search-box in a parent view, and make the switching pages child views? You can also use ng-include to switch the views according to some logic in a function inside your main controller.

Comment: I know it is a little bit twisted. The point is that one of the pages I want it to have its own different url, for SEO reasons

Comment: I've edited the last paragraph, I hope it clarifies what I want to achieve :)

Comment: Still not 100% clear. Why are you trying to use 2 separate URLs? Also, setting up an Angular app for SEO is a big issue by itself...have you already set up Angular to render static pages for crawlers (or set up some page caching service)?

Comment: @NoahB I want to have in one url the one page application (that in principle I don't mind if they are not properly crawled) and in other sepparate URL's other pages that I want to be crawled. Anyhow, if you have any tips for SEO in that scenario you're more than welcome, as this is my first project with angular :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use $stateprovider for routing. It is better than route provider. You can read out it's plus points on net over $routeProvider. Route is more of obsolete now. On state provider you just need to redirect to state And your problem will also be resolved. $state.go('content2') or $state.go('home')
 you can have nested states as well.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateprovider-1

Comment: I will look into it. Do you recommend the 0.3.1 version https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/legacy or the 1.0 alpha https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router (I am working with angular 1.5) Thanks!